# Using flash.ui.Mouse inside a class named Mouse, possible?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a class called Mouse (tracking button states in a game).  I want that class to be able to show and hide the mouse cursor.  Whenever I try to use flash.ui.Mouse.show() or flash.ui.Mouse.hide() I get the error: "Access of undefined property flash.".

I can't import flash.ui.Mouse for obvious reasons.

Is there a way to make this work?  What's the point of packages if they don't resolve these collisions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to import `flash.ui.Mouse`, and use the fully qualified class name in your code (`flash.ui.Mouse`.)

Comment: I did not know that you had to import something even if you use its fully qualified name.  That is very different form most languages.

Works a charm, thanks!

Comment: If you need access to both Mouse classes, yours and the default, you'll need to use the fully qualified name for both of them too.

Comment: Thanks Sandro -- the whole point is to never have to use anything but my own class, though. So that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this. I'm not sure of the reasoning, but it works.

```
import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName; // Goes in import section, obviously.

getDefinitionByName("flash.ui.Mouse").hide();
```

Comment: This work, but you get no compile time type checking, and the run-time definition resolving is more expensive.

Comment: Maybe that's the price you have to pay for naming a class Mouse :) jk.